# How to display a message saying doubly linked list is empty,cannot delete element from it?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have implemented a sorted doubly linked list with the help of pointers in C++.I want to display an error message on deleting the last element saying "doubly linked list is empty cannot delete any more elements" and also display a message before deleting the last element saying"the last element in the node are you sure you want to delete it"?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DoublyLinkedList.h"

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

DoublyLinkedList::DoublyLinkedList():Head(nullptr),Tail(nullptr) {

}

DoublyLinkedList::~DoublyLinkedList() {

    Node *current = Head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
    Node* next = current->Next;   //The objects pointed to by head and tail at the beginning of the destructor are deleted         
        Node* prev = current->Prev;     //  through the current pointer. Then they are deleted again at the                                                               end of the destructor.
        delete current;
        current = next;
        current = prev;
    }



}
void DoublyLinkedList::SortedInsert(const int& new_element) {


    if(new_element !=0){
        Node* np = new Node(new_element);
    if (!Head)
    {
        Head = np;
        Tail = np;
    }
    else if (new_element < Head->Element)
    {
        np->Next = Head;
        Head->Prev = np;
        Head = np;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *cur = Head->Next;
        while ((cur) && (new_element >= cur->Element))
            cur = cur->Next;

        if (cur)
        {
            np->Prev = cur->Prev;
            np->Next = cur;
            cur->Prev->Next = np;
            cur->Prev = np;
        }
        else
        {
            Tail->Next = np;
            np->Prev = Tail;
            Tail = np;
        }
        }
    }
}

void DoublyLinkedList::Delete(const int& del_element)
{
    Node *cur = Head;
    while (cur)
    {
        if (cur->Element == del_element)
        {
            if (cur->Prev)
                cur->Prev->Next = cur->Next;
            if (cur->Next)
                cur->Next->Prev = cur->Prev;
            if (cur == Head)
                Head = cur->Next;
            if (cur == Tail)
                Tail = cur->Prev;
            delete cur;
            break;
        }
        cur = cur->Next;



    }
}

void DoublyLinkedList::traverse_head() {
    Node *t = Head;
    while (t != NULL)
    {
        cout << t->Element << "\t";

        t = t->Next;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void DoublyLinkedList::traverse_tail() {


    Node *temp = Tail;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp->Element << "\t";
        temp = temp->Prev;
    }
}
main.cpp
```

// Question1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include"DoublyLinkedList.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


    int main()
    {

        DoublyLinkedList intlist;

        int i = 0, x=0,delete_elm=0;

        //intlist.SortedInsert(3);
        //intlist.SortedInsert(6);
        //intlist.SortedInsert(7);
        //intlist.SortedInsert(10);
        //intlist.SortedInsert(-1);

        //intlist.traverse_head();

        do
        {
            cout << "\nEnter value of node.Press 0 to stop\n";
            cin >> x;


            if ((!cin) || cin.peek() != '\n') {

                cin.clear();
                    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    cout << "Invalid input, no string allowed!!" << endl;
            }
            else {
                intlist.SortedInsert(x);
                i++;
            }
        } while (x != 0);
        intlist.traverse_head();

        cout << "\nTraversing Doubly Linked List head first\n";
        intlist.traverse_head();
        cout << "\nTraversing Doubly Linked List tail first\n";
        intlist.traverse_tail();
        cout << endl;
        do {
            cout << "Which element do you want to delete? 0 to stop delete operation" << endl;
            cin >> delete_elm;
            cout << endl;
            if ((!cin) || cin.peek() != '\n' || x < 0) {

                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cout << "Invalid input, no string allowed!!" << endl;
            }
            else {

                intlist.Delete(delete_elm);
                cout << "\nTraversing Doubly Linked List head first\n";
                intlist.traverse_head();
                cout << "\nTraversing Doubly Linked List tail first\n";
                intlist.traverse_tail();
                cout << endl;
            }
        } while (delete_elm != 0);

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to not be using dummy nodes, checking if the list is empty is the same as checking if the `Head` or `Tail` pointers are null. Checking if it's only one element is the same as checking if `Head->Next` is null (be sure to check that `Head` is not null first, of course).
Alternatively, you can maintain a `size` variable (incremented in insert and decremented in remove) or write a method to calculate the size by traversing the list.

Comment: Is this right?if (cur->Next == NULL || cur->Prev == NULL) {
     cout << "Deleting Last element in list" << endl;
    }
    if (Head == NULL || Tail == NULL) {
     cout << "List is empty" << endl;
    }

Comment: I am writing this under if (cur->Element == del_element){        }

Comment: That looks almost okay to me; the first condition looks like it will trigger at either end of the list, regardless of the size. (PS: I wouldn't be printing to anything inside my implementation of a doubly-linked list, though I don't know your project.)